# I would like to add specific text to get total count

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a holiday calendar for team. We have defined terms like

```
H= Holiday
B = Business trip
S= Sick
```

I would like to count total of H , S  &B for calendar year.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is in column A, you can use the following formula to count the total of H: `=COUNTIF(A:A,"H")`